# Handle condition in select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

customer:

```
 customerID     joineddate                    
 111            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000
 111            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000
 111            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000 
 211            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000
 231            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000 
 231            2004-11-10 00:00:00.000 
 411            2008-12-10 00:00:00.000
 531            2009-12-10 00:00:00.000
```

I have written the query from 2 tables where I do a join and get the result like the above. But I need to get the  result like this where I need to input my condition and get the result like below.

```
 customerID     joineddate                 indicator      
 111            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000     3
 211            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000     1
 231            2004-12-10 00:00:00.000     1
 231            2004-11-10 00:00:00.000     1
 411            2008-12-10 00:00:00.000     1
 531            2009-12-10 00:00:00.000     1
```

Comment: that doesn't make any sense ... please post the 2 tables schema and which columns you want in the output and what the condition should be

Answer (score 1):

Having absolutely no clue what your other table is named or how it is related to the `customer` table, here is my best guess:

```
SELECT c.customerID, o.joineddate, indicator = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.customer AS c
  INNER JOIN dbo.[other table] AS o
  ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  GROUP BY c.customerID, o.joineddate;
```

Comment: Thanks  fro the replay,  here  in  select  statement what  i  showed for  example contins  only 2  columns, but in real time  query iahve  7  columns   so i cannot use group by there

Comment: Why, because you can't type 7 column names? Please ask your real and complete question if answers to the current question can't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google for keyword

`GROUP BY`

and the

`COUNT()`

function.